# Суммирование value input

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, не суммирует значение `input` , что не правильно в коде:

```js
(function () {
  var inputs = document.getElementById('sum1');
  var sum=0;
  for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)  {
    sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
  }
  alert(sum);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.3.0/lodash.js"></script>

<input id='sum1' value='2' /><br />
<input id='sum1' value='2' /><br />
<input id='sum1' value='3' /><br />
<input id='sum1' value='4' /><br />
<input id='sum1' value='5' />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` должен быть уникальным на странице. Нужно использовать `class` для этого

```js
(function () {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum1');
  var sum=0;
  for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)  {
    sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
  }
  alert(sum);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.3.0/lodash.js"></script>

<input class='sum1' value='2' /><br />
<input class='sum1' value='2' /><br />
<input class='sum1' value='3' /><br />
<input class='sum1' value='4' /><br />
<input class='sum1' value='5' />
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.